# ошибка пути в flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

у меня задача указать в ссылке число символов и путь к файлу, а потом вывести символы из этого файла. При указании полного пути в ссылке появляется ошибка, что файла с таким путем нет.

```
@app.route("/head_file/<int:size>/<path:relative_path>/")

def head_file(size: int, relative_path: str):
    file = open(relative_path)
    counter = 0
    sumbols = []
    for line in file:
        for sum in line:
            if counter >= size:
                break
            else:
                sumbols.append(sum)
                counter+=1

    return sumbols
```

Пробовал запустить функцию и передать путь с кол-вом символов из переменных, так всё работает. Видимо есть какой-то нюанс с передачей в ссылке...

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Users/user/Downloads/output_file.txt'
```

Comment: ` При указании полного пути` - начните путь со слэша

Comment: Покажите пример ссылки и текст ошибки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в отсутствии первого слеша в начале пути.
Решил проблему таким образом:
`file = open('/'+relative_path)`
Возможно есть более красивое решение передать сразу в ссылке